# Can you explain to me why this works for a string and not a list please?

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define str '("3" "+" "3"))
(define list '(3 + 4))


(define (tokes str)
  (case (car str)
    ((or "+" "-" "*" "/")(write "operand")
                         (tokes (cdr str)))

                         (else (write "other"))
    ))

(define (tokelist)
  (case (car list)
    ((or "+" "-" "*" "/")(write "operand"))
    (else (write "other"))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare a String `"+"` with the procedure `+` when you're working with the list. These are different types, and they are not equal.

Try this:

```
> (string? "+")
#t
> (procedure? +)
#t
> (string? +)
#f
```

This should give you a good idea of how to solve the problem, but note:

```
> (= + +)
=: expects type <number> as 1st argument, given: #<procedure:+>;
other arguments were: #<procedure:+>
```

You need:

```
> (equal? + +)
#t
> (equal? + "+")
#f
> (equal? "+" "+")
#t
```

Using these ideas, this should get your code working:

```
(define (plus? s)
    (if (procedure? s) (equal? + s) (equal? "+" s)))
```